# matching Domain with windows server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

i have a windows server 2003 and also a .com domain . 
how can i match the domain with server ? 
for ex : my address of windows server : 73.82.x.x and domain :xxyy.com 
how can i when execute xxyy.com open the main page of my server (73.82.x.x)
Thanks In Advance .

Answer (score 1):

[DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)

Comment: we have about 500 book about DNS !!!!

Comment: How many of them have you read so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

1. This a stand-alone server, not a member of a domain
2. This server is using a public IP address, and isn't behind a firewall that's using Network Address Translation
3. By "execute xxyy.com", I assume you mean navigate to a URL inside a web browser
4. Because it's a URL you're trying to access, i'll assume that the "main page of my server" means the home page of a website you'd like to host off that server

The easiest way to do this would be to add the "DNS Server" role to the operating system, create a Forward Lookup Zone the corresponds to the domain name in question, then add a HOST record in that zone whose name is the same as the root for the zone (xxyy.com), and points to your IP address (73.82.x.x). Then add a CNAME "www" that points to the HOST  record you just created (in case people put a www in front of the main URL).

Then add the IIS role to the server. Create a website (using the wizard), point it to content that's been copied to the inetpub folder in the C: drive. Assign the main IP of the server to the website, and add 2 host header file entries as identities for the site: (1) xxyy.com (2) www.xxyy.com

Hope that helps...